# On existence of analytic continuations

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f \in H(U)$ for some open disk $U.$ Let $V \subseteq\mathbb{C}$ be the set of all points $p$ for which there exists some curve $\gamma : [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with $\gamma(0) \in U$ and $\gamma(1) = p,$ so that we can analytically continue $f$ along the curve $\gamma.$

It seems plausible to me that if $\rho : [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is any curve whose image $\rho([0,1])$ is contained entirely inside $V,$ then I ought to be able to analytically continue $f$ along $\rho.$ This works in all the examples I can think of. However, I see no way to prove it in general and was wondering if it's still true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's false.

Let $U = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \mathrm{Re}(z) > 0 \}$ and consider $f : U \to \mathbb{C}$ defined as $f(z) = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{z}}$, where each $\sqrt{\cdot}$ means the principal square root. It's not hard to see that $V = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ as the only problem could be at $z = 1$ and this point already belongs to $U$. But it is impossible to analytically continue $f$ along $\gamma(t) = e^{2 \pi i t}$ because after the full turn $\sqrt{z}$ becomes $-1$ and $\sqrt{1+u}$ has no continuation through $u = -1$.